# Swift IOS UIDatepicker - UIDatepicker displaying incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uidatepicker, ios14

So I have started taking over some of the development for an IOS app which I am still quite new at so just curious as to where to start looking for an issue such as this?

When calling the datepicker, I am not sure if this is constraint related or not and would appreciate any sort of heading.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlG7d.jpg)

Comment: Please share your code snippet showing how you are calling the date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below line and it will show date picker in old way

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    self.datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
```